# how to grep and write in to new file

Tags: linux, file

I want to read file key value from one file and grep that value from another file(file2) and write the entire content  of file2 in to file3, how can I achieve it?

**file1** : 12345 
**file2** : abc12345
abc12456

Expected out put in **file3** : abc12345

This is code I am using

```
while IFS= read -r LINE; do echo $LINE

grep '$LINE' $FILE2 >> $FILE3


done < $FILE1
```

Comment: what is the output of your script?

Comment: Why you posted your question as comment ? Delete or edit it please

Comment: I tried in so many ways I couldn't get correct output

Comment: I am not getting any value in to the file3 , I am expecting file2 entire content in to file3

Comment: This below code works fine , I got the expected out put  while IFS= read -r LINE; do
echo $LINE
stateId=$(echo $line)

echo $stateId
grep ^${stateId}  $FILE2 >> $FILE3

done < $FILE1

Answer (score 1):

This should read space separated keys file: "file1" to grep "file2" and if some found write content of "file2" to "file3".

```
#!/bin/sh

IFS=' ' read -r -a FKEYS <<< `cat ./file1`

for next_key in ${FKEYS[@]}; do
    if [ "$next_key" != "" ]; then
        RESULT=`grep $next_key ./file2`
        if [ "$RESULT" != "" ]; then
            echo $RESULT > ./file3
            exit
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hi this didn't work, can any one one suggest. Even my previous resolution dosn't work

Comment: Yes its not giving any error , the file writes empty

Comment: echo $FILE1


This is the  script I used 
while IFS= read -r LINE; do
echo $LINE
stateId=$(echo $LINE)

echo $stateId


$grep `cat $FILE1` $FILE2 > $FILE3


done < $FILE1

Comment: while IFS= read -r LINE; do
#echo $LINE
stateId=$(echo $LINE)

echo $stateId
grep "$stateId"  $FILE2 >> $FILE3

#$grep "12345" $FILE2 >> $FILE3

#grep $LINE $FILE2
done < $FILE1

Comment: Just add to file1 part of string from the file2)

Comment: THis command works fine  $grep "12345" $FILE2 >> $FILE3 but only when I use variable $grep "$stateId" $FILE2 >> $FILE3 its not working

Comment: # cat ./file1
45
# cat ./file2
qwerty12345678
# grep `cat ./file1` ./file2 > ./file3
# cat ./file3
qwerty12345678
-------
Is it right?

Comment: Yes this what I am expecting as output

Comment: grep 'cat $FILE1' $FILE2 >> $FILE3 tried this its not working

Comment: one more thing file1 contains multiple rows  and file2 also contains multiple rows.

Comment: file 1: 123456
789101   file 2 :                           abc123456cvbbb
dfc789101rftg

Comment: I want to read file key value from one file and grep that value from another file(file2) and write the entire content  of file2 in to file3, how can I achieve it?

**file1** : 12345 
            78910    
**file2** : abc12345
            abc78910
abc12456

Expected out put in **file3** : abc12345
                                abc78910

Comment: Looks like Grep is not recognizing the variables

Comment: Please define your task in other way, because seems I can't catch all what you need.

Comment: pluse-uno for a working solution and tech support, but please join the 90's and use the `$(cmd)` form of command substitution ;-) . But do you really mean to wipe out `file3` each time a new value is found? I would think  you want `>>`. Finally, not sure the point of a lot of this, wouldn't `grep -Ff file1 file2 > file3` solve this problem? (`man grep` please) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Alex, as I mentioned I have multiple records Ss in to the file1 and more records in file2 , I have to read all the records one by one and grep it and write in to the new file